# How to combine records in a Query in MS ACCESS?

Tags: ms-access

I Have a Query as below in MS ACCESS:

**InvoiceID

ItemID

ContractorAmount

SupervisorAmount**

And I made a form an ask from user 2 invoice numbers in 2 Textboxes and for example get:
 InvoiceID = 20 as current invoice number 
 InvoiceID = 19 as before invoice number

I need to make a Query like below:

**ItemID

ContarctorCurrentAmount

SupervisorCurrentAmount

ContarctorBeforeAmount

SupervisorBeforeAmount**

I searched internet but couldn’t find my answer, your help is appreciated.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show what you already tried and what is not working.

Comment: I need to make a report that in each row shows amounts of records for current invoice and before invoice together then i tried to solve it using CROSSTAB query but the problem is that i have 2 fields in each record of my table one is contractor amount and another is supervisor amount

Comment: It may be a language barrier but your question doesn't make much sense. Try showing what your current attempt results in, and what your expected result is.